# Android run code in Service all the time

Tags: android, multithreading, service, client, server

I want to create a Service that runs in the background and checks if the client sends a message to the server and answers to it.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
package com.server.test;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerService extends Service {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    Thread serverThread;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        System.out.println("hello1");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Server Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        serverThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("hello2");
                    try {
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
                    }

                    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("hello3");
                        try {

                            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
                            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); 
                            message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                            System.out.println(message);
                            inputStreamReader.close();
                            clientSocket.close();

                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        serverThread.start();
    }
}
```

The problem is, that when the code is in onCreate(), it only gets executed when the service gets created, and I want it to run all the time. So where do I have to put the code in the Service class so it runs all the time?

Best Regards,
Alex

Comment: Your thread is started in OnCreate(). But if OnCreate() ends your thread is still running. Or not?

Comment: I don't think so ... I tried to place a couple of System.out.println() inside the thread and they only print once. Another question: How do I do a code inside an Activity that gets executed all the time? Like where I can do x++; or something and then check if it exceeds a value or so? because code in onCreated only gets executed once and I don't know where to put it otherwise

Comment: By that I mean where is the main loop?

Comment: After you close the clientsocket  you call again accept(). So a new client can connect. There is nothing that finishes `while(true)` except an exception. So it continues running. Please do not ask other questions in this post.

Comment: But hello3 only outputs one time ..

Comment: Then find out where it leaves the loop or sticks in the loop.  Is there a client accepted? Place a log statement there. You log the received message. What is printed? Just place log statements after every statement in the loop.

Comment: As you can see in the Code in the first post, i placed a couple printlns to print random text. But hello1, hello2, hello3 only print once, while hello3 should be printed non-stop because it is in a loop? Or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: Please add more print statements. I already asked you to do so. And answer my question about message print. Add a print to that other catch block too.

Comment: So I added prints to all the catch blocks, none of them get executed. I also added a couple more prints in the loop and try blocks and all of them only execute once

Comment: Edit your code here too so it represents your actual code. I think `.accept()` is the last statement which waits until a client connects. So you have no client.